# Connecting Washing Machine Hose to Kitchen Sink

Tags: plumbing, faucet, washing-machine

I just bought a portable washing machine for my apartment but I’m having trouble connecting the hose to the kitchen faucet. This is what came with the washer.[image]

**picture for reference**

Answer (score 0):

It is a quick connect. If you push the white ring down the top part will pop out allowing you to screw it on to the faucet while connecting the hose to the other part. Then just push it in to connect the two for washing machine, or disconnect for faucet use. Obviously you need to unscrew the faucet cap first.

Comment: I managed to unscrew the faucet cap. Wow. This whole time I was thinking they sent me the wrong piece. But now that I’ve done that, what about the piece in the actual faucet? Idk what it’s called but I think I have a flat faucet with an inside aerator.

Comment: @ZoellFoye just take the aerator out and keep it.